# loader-utils throwing critical vulnerability error in Angular 13

Tags: angular, npm, npm-audit

Recently Upgraded Angular version to 13 and found 5 critical vulnerabilities

```
loader-utils  <=1.4.1 || 2.0.0 - 2.0.3
Severity: critical
Prototype pollution in webpack loader-utils - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-76p3-8jx3-jpfq
Prototype pollution in webpack loader-utils - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-76p3-8jx3-jpfq
loader-utils is vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service (ReDoS) via url variable - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-3rfm-jhwj-7488
loader-utils is vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service (ReDoS) via url variable - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-3rfm-jhwj-7488
loader-utils is vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service (ReDoS) - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-hhq3-ff78-jv3g
loader-utils is vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service (ReDoS) - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-hhq3-ff78-jv3g
No fix available
node_modules/@angular-builders/custom-webpack/node_modules/resolve-url-loader/node_modules/loader-utils
node_modules/loader-utils
  @angular-devkit/build-optimizer  0.901.0-next.0 - 0.1200.0-rc.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of loader-utils
  node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer
  resolve-url-loader  0.0.1-experiment-postcss || 1.0.3 - 2.0.0 || 3.0.1 - 3.1.4 || 4.0.0-alpha.1 - 4.0.0-beta.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of loader-utils
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/@angular-builders/custom-webpack/node_modules/resolve-url-loader
```

Here is my package.json

```js
{
  "name": "dashboard",
  "version": "0.0.799",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=4200 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "buildDev": "ng build --prod --base-href /angular-cq/event-dashboard/ --deploy-url /angular-cq/event-dashboard/",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "node patch.js",
    "start:local": "ng serve -c=local --port=4400",
    "dev": "ng serve --port=4300",
    "build-prod-patch": "npm version patch && node ./replace.build.js && ng build --prod && node ./versioning.build.js",
    "build-prod-no-patch": "node ./replace.build.js && ng build --prod && node ./versioning.build.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@amcharts/amcharts4": "^4.10.29",
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1202.18",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/animations": "^13.3.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/common": "^13.3.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.3.12",
    "@angular/core": "^13.3.12",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^13.0.0-beta.38",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.3.12",
    "@angular/localize": "^13.3.12",
    "@angular/material": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.3.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.3.12",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^13.3.12",
    "@angular/router": "^13.3.12",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^13.3.12",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^1.2.3",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^18.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.10.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.30",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@henkkelder/ng2-signalr": "^12.0.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^12.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-base": "^19.4.56",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-buttons": "^19.4.42",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-calendars": "^19.4.48",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-dropdowns": "^19.4.56",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-grids": "^19.4.56",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-inputs": "^19.4.47",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-navigations": "^19.4.47",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-notifications": "^19.4.52",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-popups": "^19.4.53",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-splitbuttons": "^19.4.52",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-layouts": "^19.4.52",
    "@types/file-saver": "^1.3.0",
    "@types/highcharts": "^5.0.29",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^13.0.0",
    "angular-linky": "^1.2.2",
    "angular2-highcharts": "^0.5.5",
    "arcgis-js-api": "^4.26.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.6.11",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "crypto-js": "^3.3.0",
    "esri-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.32",
    "highcharts": "^6.1.3",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.12",
    "intl-tel-input": "^17.0.13",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.9.23",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "ng-mocks": "^13.5.1",
    "ngx-autosize": "^1.8.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.0.0",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^12.2.1",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.3.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^8.0.2",
    "ngx-intl-tel-input": "^3.2.0",
    "ngx-textarea-autosize": "^2.0.3",
    "primeicons": "^5.0.0",
    "primeng": "^13.2.1",
    "replace-in-file": "^6.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "sass": "~1.58.0",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "signalr": "^2.4.0",
    "socket.io-client": "2.2.0",
    "stream": "^0.0.2",
    "subsink": "^1.0.1",
    "three-dots": "^0.2.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.3.10",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.3.12",
    "@angular/language-service": "^13.3.12",
    "@types/faker": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.16",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/jest": "^29.4.4",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "faker": "^5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.9",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.6.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.8"
  }
}
```

So the issue is because of the vulnerable version of loader-utils,found it in package-lock.json and the version is 2.0.1 or 1.4.0 for some transitive dependencies.

I found that loader-utils version 2.0.4 and 3.2.1 has been fixed for this vulnerability hence I did a manual upgrade in package-lock.json to the above version, but that's giving some compilation issues hence removed that now.
Kindly let me know what can be done to fix this issue

Edit:Adding npm ls utils-loader

```js
+-- @angular-builders/custom-webpack@10.0.1
| `-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1002.1
|   +-- @angular-devkit/build-optimizer@0.1002.1
|   | `-- loader-utils@2.0.0 deduped
|   +-- @jsdevtools/coverage-istanbul-loader@3.0.5
|   | `-- loader-utils@2.0.0 deduped
|   +-- babel-loader@8.1.0
|   | `-- loader-utils@1.4.2
|   +-- copy-webpack-plugin@6.0.3
|   | `-- loader-utils@2.0.0 deduped
|   +-- css-loader@4.2.2
|   | `-- loader-utils@2.0.0 deduped
|   +-- file-loader@6.0.0
|   | `-- loader-utils@2.0.0 deduped
|   +-- less-loader@6.2.0
|   | `-- loader-utils@2.0.0 deduped
|   +-- loader-utils@2.0.0
|   +-- mini-css-extract-plugin@0.10.0
|   | `-- loader-utils@1.4.2
|   +-- postcss-loader@3.0.0
|   | `-- loader-utils@1.4.2
|   +-- raw-loader@4.0.1
|   | `-- loader-utils@2.0.0 deduped
|   +-- resolve-url-loader@3.1.2
|   | +-- adjust-sourcemap-loader@3.0.0
|   | | `-- loader-utils@2.0.0 deduped
|   | `-- loader-utils@1.2.3
|   +-- sass-loader@10.0.1
|   | `-- loader-utils@2.0.0 deduped
|   +-- source-map-loader@1.0.2
|   | `-- loader-utils@2.0.0 deduped
|   +-- style-loader@1.2.1
|   | `-- loader-utils@2.0.0 deduped
|   +-- stylus-loader@3.0.2
|   | `-- loader-utils@1.4.2
|   +-- webpack@4.44.1
|   | `-- loader-utils@1.4.2
|   `-- worker-plugin@5.0.0
|     `-- loader-utils@1.4.2
`-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@13.3.11
  +-- babel-loader@8.2.5
  | `-- loader-utils@2.0.0 deduped
  +-- loader-utils@3.2.1
  `-- resolve-url-loader@5.0.0
    +-- adjust-sourcemap-loader@4.0.0
    | `-- loader-utils@2.0.0 deduped
    `-- loader-utils@2.0.0 deduped
```

Comment: could you run `npm ls loader-utils` ?

Comment: yes.Edited question with the dependency tree

Comment: You could try to update `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` to v13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to `angular-builders/custom-webpack` v13 will update `loader-utils` for you.